# Company login page displayed twice while using Azure active directory in Android

Tags: android, azure-active-directory

I am trying to integrate Azure AD in Android app using my organizations tenant id.
I referred this library 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-android

The current flow is

1. Microsoft login page(with my Company name)
2. Company login page
3. If authenticated, proceed to App

The entire flow works fine but i see a weird issue here.

If i set the Prompt behavior as ALWAYS, the second step (Company login page) appears twice.

It means when enter my credentials in company login page and when i hit login the page reloads.

Second time when i enter the credentials and hit login, the flow proceeds to the next step.

This only happens when i set prompt behavior as ALWAYS.

If I set prompt behavior as AUTO, the login page is shown only once and the entire flow works fine.
What am I doing wrong here ?

```
Promptbehavior --> AUTO
mAuthContext.acquireToken(getActivity(), RESOURCE_ID, CLIENT_ID, REDIRECT_URI, PromptBehavior.Auto, getAuthInteractiveCallback());

Promptbehavior --> ALWAYS
mAuthContext.acquireToken(getActivity(), RESOURCE_ID, CLIENT_ID, REDIRECT_URI, PromptBehavior.Always, getAuthInteractiveCallback());
```

Comment: This feature is in public preview phase. please feel free to add it to open issue list. Let me check with the respected engineer on this and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend all apps to begin using v2 / MSAL rather than v1/ ADAL (below). We're supporting ADAL. Here's an MSAL Sample:

```
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-android-native
```

Hope it helps.